# Please explain this in layman's terms

Tags: wilcoxon-mann-whitney-test, z-score

I did a mann-whitney u test.

There is a significant difference - p value below 0.05

It also provided a Z score along with a W and U score.

What is the z score for and what can I do with it?

Comment: Please edit the title of your question to something more informative.

Comment: A Mann Whitney test does *not* compare median ranks.

Answer (score 5):

With large sample sizes, it is not straightforward to compute a p-value directly from the U score. So instead, an equation is used to compute a z ratio from U. Then it is straightforward to compute the p-value from that. The z ratio is used in the normal distribution. It is how many standard deviations from the mean a value is. If the z is greater than 1.96 (or less than -1.96), the p-value is less than 0.05.

Comment: thank you so much! so it's like an intermediate value in calculating the p value from the U score? And the stat that i should focus on is the p value? Really really grateful for your help!

Comment: @isuckatmaths  precisely!